# Opening TabbedBarController from TableViewController

Tags: swift, tabbarcontroller

This is my tableViewController where I'm calling the tabbedView, however I'm getting an exception on this line `let viewController = segue.destination as! EViewController` the exception is:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x7fff897a2cd8) to 'Test.EViewController'
```

Which is weird, because EViewController is a UIViewController and not a UITabBarController

EviewController is the first ViewController in the TabbedViewController, should I be calling the parent controller? And how would I do that? I want to pass data to the tabbedViewController

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedName = (self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel?.text)!
    performSegue(withIdentifier: “menu”, sender: self)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.names.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == “menu”) {
        let viewController = segue.destination as! EViewController
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem happens with those code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == “menu”) {
        let viewController = segue.destination as! EViewController
    }
}
```

`segue.destination` should be a `UITabBarController` instead of `EViewController`, and you use `as!` to convert `UITabBarController` to be `EViewController` forcibly and it will be error.

in this case, you should take a look about `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`, the view stack is

```
|UITabBarController|
    viewControllers:
    |EViewController|
    ...
```

so you should use `segue.destination.topViewController` to fix this issue.

Comment: Oh, you're right, but if I'm not using my custom controller (which is a UIViewController within the Tab Controller), how can I set the properties?

Comment: is same there, just without the `as!` to set class type

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand.

Still new to Swift.

I tried renewing the code like so, but now I have a sigabrt

// first line gives me sigabrt
```let viewController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
let eVC = viewController.viewControllers.first as! EViewController
eVC.name = name```

Comment: btw topViewController isn't a property of destination, because destination is a uivTabBarController